# Dynamic version in library not resolving with maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, artifactory

So in our enterprise deployment that of course hosts/proxies everything via Artifactory and any complications that come with that.

We're creating a library that publishes a pom with this.

```xml
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>[2.5,3)</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

this is actually generated by Gradle but looks correct to me. Gradle has no problem finding this dependency (there are definitely versions available) for the build.

Maven generates the following error. It has problems finding the dynamic version using its own syntax...

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:[2.5,3) (absent): Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:[2.5,3) in artcentral
```

```
Apache Maven 3.9.5 (57804ffe001d7215b5e7bcb531cf83df38f93546)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Only happens with Maven versions earlier than 4.x when scope type is `import`.

Comment: The usage spring-boot-starter-parent as a scope import is not really correct better `spring-boot-dependencies` instead... apart from that spring boot version 2.X is end of support (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) and most important dependencyManagement does NOT support version ranges (for Maven 4 yes) but not for Maven 3.X apart from the general bad idea to use version ranges...

Comment: @khmarbaise cute that you think I have some control over which version of spring boot we're on... thanks for the correction though. I missed the memo on `-dependencies` I guess.

Comment: I closed as duplicate, but in case anyone needs a fix for gradle publishing https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:resolved_dependencies